# Android camera create bitmap failed

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

My coding have a problem, which is unable to capture the live current frame.
This is my camera live scene class, When I call the getBitmap function to capture the on preview frame scene then I get an error like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: yuv cannot be null
```

Any guidance will be appreciated~

I have doing debugging, the bytes has a big value of array for storing some number then I assign it to a global variable byteArray, but I dunno why I get null for byteArray

This is my coding:

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Camera mCamera;
boolean isPreviewRunning = false;
private byte[] byteArray;
private Bitmap mBitmap;

CameraSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    SurfaceHolder mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized(this) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Camera", "mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);");
        }
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                byteArray = bytes;
            }
        });
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized(this) {
        try {
            if (mCamera!=null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                isPreviewRunning=false;
                mCamera.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Camera", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    try {
        YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(byteArray, ImageFormat.NV21, 600, 1000, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 600, 1000);

        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(rect, 75, byteArrayOutputStream);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), 0, byteArrayOutputStream.size(), options);

        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mBitmap;
}

}
```

stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: yuv cannot be null
        at android.graphics.YuvImage.<init>(YuvImage.java:93)
        at com.etoff.appsopengl.CameraSurfaceView.getBitmap(CameraSurfaceView.java:69)
        at com.etoff.appsopengl.Stage$MyRenderer.onDrawFrame(Stage.java:168)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1467)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1221)
```

Comment: please post your stacktrace...

Comment: the error i oredi post up there

Comment: I am unable to find any variable or object named delcared as yuv.

Comment: I have update the stack trace, mean tat my byteArray is null

Comment: The error is inside the initialization of your custom class `YuvImage`. When you call `new YuvImage(byteArray, ImageFormat.NV21, 600, 1000, null);` Its likely that inside the initialization is a variable called `yuv` that is not set properly. but you are trying to use it like it has been.

Comment: yuv is the byteArray, but how to fix it

Comment: post the code for YUVIMAGE class also..

Comment: YUVIMAGE is android built in class

Comment: where are you calling getBitmap() function. Make sure your byteArray is not null before calling getBitmap().

Comment: Your right. YUVImage is android. Didnt realise sorry :).  I dont think your `byteArray` is set, so you are trying to create an image with null data.

Comment: my problem now is dunno why the byteArray is null, since I was set in surface created method

Comment: begging some1 to help me, i was start doing this for almost 8 hours

Comment: Its set in `setPreviewCallback` which may not be called, for what ever reason. Im going to have to leave you to investigate. But i suggest logging or breakpointing this method to see if its set. Or starting preview After the method is set

Comment: You could also intialise the `byteArray` to empty byte array (initialized) rather than null.  to overcome any potential first attempt issues before preview is setting a byte array.

Comment: I just doing a debugging, the bytes is has damn big array for storing some number then i assign to global variable byteArray, but I dunno why I get null

Answer (score 0):

The byte array you receive from `onPreviewFrame()` is not locked; it may get discarded by the camera at any time. The easiest fix is to copy its contents:

```
…
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
    byteArray = bytes.clone();
}
```

Also, make sure that you check `byteArray != null` in `getBitmap()`, and synchronize this method with `onPreviewFrame()`.

Not that this approach is efficient. It produces many memory allocations and copies. It is much better to use [Camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback)), and handle the camera buffers manually, but it requires more programming discipline.

Comment: Please post the updated code if you need help with it

Comment: same as above i just add the .clone

Comment: But you also need to check `byteArray != null` in `getBitmap()`, and synchronize this method with `onPreviewFrame()` - you missed this part?

Comment: in other class i declare like this private CameraSurfaceView csv; csv = new CameraSurfaceView(context); and call like this newBitmap = csv.getBitmap();

Comment: Ya i used .clone() in the method but in get bitmap still null

Comment: Sir the way i declare and call the getBitmap correct?

Comment: from what you wrote here, I believe that you call `getBitmap()` too early. It may take a while for the camera to get initialized and deliver its frames.

Comment: Hi Sir I using setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer() and I got checking getBitmap it's the byteArray null? and I get the byteArray null... Why it's still null???

Comment: and I also get also isPreviewRunning = false